# Negative lower confidence interval limit for a proportion using svyby() for survey weighted data

Tags: r, survey

How do you ensure the lower confidence interval limit is non-negative for a proportion when dealing with survey weighted data?

This is the code:

```
svy_design <- svydesign(ids = ~block, strata = ~strata_study, weights = ~wt, data = data, nest = TRUE, fpc = NULL)

svyby(~binary_outcome,by=~binary_exposure, design=svy_design, FUN=svymean, data=data,keep.var = TRUE, vartype = "ci")
```

Result as follows:

```
  binary_exposure binary_outcome0 binary_outcome1 ci_l.binary_outcome0 ci_l.binary_outcome1 ci_u.binary_outcome0 ci_u.binary_outcome1
1               1        0.9858986       0.01410138             0.9782720           0.006474771             0.9935252            0.02172798
2               2        0.9264685       0.07353151             0.8489539          -0.003983028             1.0039830            0.15104605
```

The lower confidence interval for the proportion is reported as -0.003983028. How to ensure that the estimates are bounded 0 and above?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `svyciprop`: eg, compare

```
> svyby(~I(emer==0), ~stype, svyciprop, design=dclus1, method="mean",vartype="ci")
  stype I(emer == 0)        ci_l      ci_u
E     E    0.2083333  0.08601926 0.3306474
H     H    0.2142857 -0.04681564 0.4753871
M     M    0.0800000 -0.04023591 0.2002359
```

```
> svyby(~I(emer==0), ~stype, svyciprop, design=dclus1, method="logit",vartype="ci")
  stype I(emer == 0)       ci_l      ci_u
E     E    0.2083333 0.11139102 0.3558571
H     H    0.2142857 0.05467787 0.5625459
M     M    0.0800000 0.01669209 0.3081661
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Which method would be appropriate here, I'm reading into the documentation and there seem to be a variety. Are there any books/references that provide guidance on choice of method ?

Comment: `logit` is pretty widely used and seems to work fairly reliably.  (but if there was a clear advantage for one of the methods I wouldn't have implemented so many of them.)

Answer (score 1):

`svyby` uses `confint` function with `method='Wald'` argument to process confidence interval. Wald method can lead to negative values. You should use `method='likelihood'` instead.
I haven't find a way to change the method directly from `svyby` in the documentation, but you can call `confint()` directly on a `svyglm` object with `method='likelihood'`.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried the likelihood intervals and they yield positive values, however I have mostly seen wald intervals be reported in publications. There were other methods “logit”, “likelihood”, “asin”, “beta”, “mean”, “xlogit” in the documentations, do you know of any references that can help chose the most appropriate method for my data? Thanks

Comment: Proper method depends on assumptions you can make on your data. Here is an example of 5 methods you could use on proportions: https://towardsdatascience.com/five-confidence-intervals-for-proportions-that-you-should-know-about-7ff5484c024f 
You could also try bootstrap which doesn't rely on assumptions.

Comment: logit and likelihood are probably the best.  People use Wald for simplicity, because they don't have the survey package.  @MendelYev: none of those methods are valid for weighted survey data

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Would the same be true for survey weighted logistic regression using svyglm()? Is likelihood ratio also the preferred or more suitable method here too but wald is just easier to compute from the logistic regression model?

Comment: Also, I would also like to compare the proportions between groups using a chisq-test. There are a variety of methods under svychisq(): “F”, “Chisq”, “Wald”, “adjWald”, “lincom”, “saddlepoint”, which test should accompany the "logit" or "likelihood" confidence intervals? Would it make sense to use the "adjWald" svychisq test method for pvalues with"logit" or "likelihood" confidence intervals for the proportions?

Comment: Wald tests in logistic regression are better; that's what the `logit` method is actually doing. The log odds ratio is a good scale for Wald tests -- the distribution is roughly symmetric and unbounded -- but the probability scale is terrible.  In a sense the `adjWald` test goes better with `logit` and the `F` test goes better with `likelihood`, but the `F` test (or `lincom`) has much better control of Type I error so I'd probably use that.